# Make SKAction playSoundFileNamed multilanguage ready

Tags: internationalization, sprite-kit, xcode6, avaudioplayer

Using Sprite-kit to play a sound is easy:

```
SKAction *readText = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"soundfile.mp3" waitForCompletion:YES];
```

But, how can I internationalize this sound, so when the language is changed to spanish, it takes the spanish version, english or other languages?

I imported the file "soundifle.mp3" into Xcode and selected Localization, base, English and spanish; then placed each version in the corresponding folder. Unfortunately the simulator always runs the same file. What am I missing?

If I use:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString * sndPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"soundfile" ofType:@"mp3"];
NSLog(@"Returning soundPath:%@",sndPath);
SKAction *readText = [SKAction playSoundFileNamed:sndPath waitForCompletion:YES];
```

When I use that method I get:
Returning soundPath:/Users/user/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/3F1151AD-856B-4F78-B504-784A8E3E7171/Appname.app/es.lproj/soundfile.mp3

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Missing Resource', reason: 'Resource /Users/hector/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.1/Applications/3F1151AD-856B-4F78-B504-784A8E3E7171/Appname.app/ca.lproj/soundfile.mp3 cannont be found in the main bundle'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 0):

I would expect it to work that way, that it'd just pick the file from the right language folder. Presuming you've already checked the built application whether the sounds *actually* got copied into the folders, and verified you used the correct language folder names and such, I could only help in working around this:

According to the docs, you can pass a file path to `+playSoundFileNamed:waitForCompletion:`. So I would just use the regular `NSBundle pathForSoundResource:` method (see `NSSound.h`) to generate the proper file path for the current language, then pass in that path instead of just a short name. You could define a method like that as a category on SKAction to make it easier, e.g. `+ (SKAction *)tor_playLocalizedSoundFileNamed:(NSString*)soundFile waitForCompletion:(BOOL)wait;`

PS - A few more things to test: Do you have two copies of the sound? I.e. one in Resources, the other in Resources/English.lproj or whatever it was? If not, have you checked what happens if you don't put a copy of the sound in the base localization?

Comment: I tried that but it looks like NSBundle for iOS does not have the pathForSoundResource: method. How could I accomplish that in iOS programming?

Comment: There's always the generic pathForResource:ofType:

Comment: I edited the question with extra info. Unfortunately parthForResource finds the file, but SKAction can't find it!